# How to split multi node XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

The XML file has nodes like this:
`<ggl> <entities> <entity> (..nodes..) </entity> <entity> (..nodes..) </entity> etc.` for millions of *entity*`</entities> </ggl>`

The code below worked when a test XML file had only one  with  (..nodes..)  etc. . However, with these added layers, it does not seem to work. This is the first code I am trying to write in C# so any help would be great!

```
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //XmlDocument TEST = new XmlDocument();
        //xmls.Load("c:\\New.xml");
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"File.xml"); // loading source xml
        var xmls = xml.Root.Elements().ToArray(); // split into elements
                                                  //var abc = xml.Root.Elements();

        XElement srcTree = new XElement("entities");

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            using (var file = File.CreateText(string.Format("xml{0}.xml", i + 1)))
            {
                srcTree.Add(xmls[i]);
                if (i == 2) 
                {
                    file.Write(srcTree.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others and explain exactly what part isn't working. Do you get exceptions? Do you get incorrect data/result? What is the result you expect? Why do you try to read only 2 entries when you have millions of entities? Maybe you are even looking for a solution in XSLT.

Comment: You did not post enough data for us to understand what you are trying to do.